# PostgreSQL: Efficiently aggregate array columns as part of a group by

Tags: arrays, postgresql, group-by, aggregate-functions

We wish to perform a GROUP BY operation on a table. The original table contains an ARRAY column. Within a group, the content of these arrays should be transformed into a single array with unique elements. No ordering of these elements is required. contain
Newest PostgreSQL versions are available.

Example original table:

```
  id | fruit  | flavors               
---: | :----- | :---------------------
     | apple  | {sweet,sour,delicious}
     | apple  | {sweet,tasty}         
     | banana | {sweet,delicious}
```

Exampled desired result:

```
count_total | aggregated_flavors          
----------: | :---------------------------
          1 | {delicious,sweet} 
          2 | {sour,tasty,delicious,sweet}
```

SQL toy code to create the original table:

```
CREATE TABLE example(id int, fruit text, flavors text ARRAY);
INSERT INTO example (fruit, flavors)
VALUES ('apple', ARRAY [ 'sweet','sour', 'delicious']),
       ('apple', ARRAY [ 'sweet','tasty' ]),
       ('banana', ARRAY [ 'sweet', 'delicious']);
```

We have come up with a solution requiring transforming the array to s

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_total,
       array
  (SELECT DISTINCT unnest(string_to_array(replace(replace(string_agg(flavors::text, ','), '{', ''), '}', ''), ','))) AS aggregated_flavors
FROM example
GROUP BY fruit
```

However we think this is not optimal, and may be problematic as we assume that the string does neither contain "{", "}", nor ",". It feels like there must be functions to combine arrays in the way we need, but we weren't able to find them.

Thanks a lot everyone!

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are trying with the many nested string operations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=ca02e8d318c4396c920902e950bee838)

Assuming each record contains a unique `id` value:

```
SELECT
    fruit,
    array_agg(DISTINCT flavor),      -- 2
    COUNT(DISTINCT id)               -- 3
FROM
    example,
    unnest(flavors) AS flavor        -- 1
GROUP BY fruit
```

1. `unnest()` array elements
2. Group by `fruit` value: `array_agg()` for distinct `flavor`s
3. Group by `fruit` value: `COUNT()` for distinct `id`s with each `fruit` group.

---

if the `id` column is really empty, you could generate the `id` values for example with the [`row_number()` window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=358a99ab9ce90d6f946f77eeea87d647)

```
SELECT
    * 
FROM (
    SELECT
        *, row_number() OVER () as id
    FROM example
) s,
unnest(flavors) AS flavor
```

Comment: Great answer, works like a charm! I would have never gotten the idea to shift the unnest to the FROM section. As a bonus, this approach extends naturally to aggregation of multiple Array columns.